# Extract and manipulate template arguments in C++

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

I'm trying to implement a template which can return the sum of its template arguments. The number of template arguments varies so therefor I would like to make a variadic template accepting a parameter pack. I was able to make a function template which can do the following:

```
Sum(1,2,3)
```

But I also want to be able to do something like:

```
Sum<1,2,3>())
```

Can someone explain how I can extract these templates arguments and store the sum of those arguments in something like a struct?

Thanks already!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use variadic templates, template specialization, and compile-time recursion.

```
// Forward-declaration of a `Sum` variadic template class
// that takes some integers as template parameters
template<int...> 
struct Sum;

// Case 0: variadic template pack is not empty 
// (match one integer `TX` and any remaining integers `TXs...`)
// (`TXs...` can be empty)
template<int TX, int... TXs> 
struct Sum<TX, TXs...> 
    : std::integral_constant<int, TX + Sum<TXs...>::value>
{

};

// Case 1: variadic template pack is empty
template<>
struct Sum<> 
    : std::integral_constant<int, 0>
{

};

int main()
{
    assert(Sum<1, 2, 3>::value == 6);
}
```

---

Also, if you have an already-working `constexpr` function `getSum(...)`, you can wrap it with a struct:

```
template<int... TXs> 
struct Sum
{
    constexpr static int value{getSum(TXs...)};
};
```

Comment: You forgot something : `Sum(1,2,3)` should work as well as `Sum<1,2,3>()`. You didn't answer at all.

Comment: @Ninetainedo: Maybe I misunderstood the original question, but didn't the OP say he managed to implement `Sum(1,2,3)` and needed help on implementing `Sum<1,2,3>`?

Comment: That's correct. Vittorio Romeo answered my question :)

Comment: @HenryMaathuis My bad, sorry ! From your code examples, I didn't think a struct would answer !

Comment: @HenryMaathuis: if you are satisfied, do you mind accepting this answer so that the question can be marked as "solved"? Thanks.